# node-amqp — proper way to handle connection in Express app?

Tags: node.js, express, rabbitmq, node-amqp

I'm using Express with node-amqp. My goal is to create amqpConnection and save it to global object before server starts and in Express routes use previously created `globals.amqp_connection`.

```
### server.coffee

app.use( ... )
...

# create RabbitMQ connection before server starts
connection = require("amqp").createConnection
  host: "localhost"

connection.on "ready", ->

  console.log "Got connection.on(\"ready\") event from node-amqp..."

  # make amqp_connection accessible from any point of application
  globals.amqp_connection = connection

  server = globals.http.createServer(app).listen(8082)

  console.log "Express server is listening 8082..."
```

The problem is `connection.on "ready"`-event is fired eveytime I call a route. I may suppose that's because of Express way of serving http-requests — executing server.js for every route called. So, for every request, a new instance of `connection` is created and on it's "ready" app tries to create one more instance of Express server.

How to make amqp_connection accessible from any point of my app, but no doubling `require("amqp").createConnection()` in every point where I need to push something to RabbitMQ?

**UPD:** or maybe there is no problem with Express. node-amqp seems to fire ready event every second after creation. Don't know if it's correct behavior

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ready event fired multiple 'cause of connection error:

https://github.com/postwait/node-amqp/issues/255